# Reading a file in MVC 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to access my `create.sql` file in the main folder of my server. It contains queries to set up my database. I have a problem to access this file at all.

1) I cannot really get there through `Configuration`. I can only use `AddJsonFile`, `AddXmlFile`, and `AddIniFile`. And I guess this is not the best idea to put a big sql file into any of those.

2) [Mvc source on github](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc) seems to be missing `MapPath`. So no possibility of using `Server.MapPath("~/create.sql")`.

How to achieve this then?

Comment: `MapPath` is part of ASP.NET.

Comment: You can use the ApplicationBasePath property on IApplicationEnvironment service to get the root path of your application...curious, what is the scenario that you are trying to acheive?

Comment: @KiranChalla It works, wonderful, thank you! If you wish, please write it as an answer and I will accept it :) And regarding your question - I would like to build the structure of my database (tables, functions, etc.) on a server startup.

Comment: Check this: https://www.codingfusion.com/Post/How-to-Read-a-Text-File-in-ASP-NET-MVC

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As already noticed and mentioned in the comments it seems that there is no `MapPath` in ASP.NET VNext (MVC 6). I found the workaround here:

http://forums.asp.net/t/2005166.aspx?HostingEnvironment+Equivalent+For+MapPath

Basically you need to get the `ApplicationBasePath` from `IApplicationEnvironment` interface, which currently is implemented as a service, following below the solution:

```
    private readonly IApplicationEnvironment _appEnvironment;

    public HomeController(IApplicationEnvironment appEnvironment)
    {
        _appEnvironment = appEnvironment;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var rootPath = _appEnvironment.ApplicationBasePath;
        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

And also, instead of injecting `IApplicationEnvironment` you may use `PlatformServices.Default.Application.ApplicationBasePath`.

**EDIT**: Here's a possible implementation of MapPath/UnmapPath as extensions to `PlatformServices`:

```
removed (see EDIT2)
```

**EDIT2**: Slightly modified, `IsPathMapped()` added as well as some checks to see if path mapping/unmapping is really needed.

```
public static class PlatformServicesExtensions
{
    public static string MapPath(this PlatformServices services, string path)
    {
        var result = path ?? string.Empty;
        if (services.IsPathMapped(path) == false)
        {
            var wwwroot = services.WwwRoot();
            if (result.StartsWith("~", StringComparison.Ordinal))
            { 
                result = result.Substring(1); 
            }
            if (result.StartsWith("/", StringComparison.Ordinal))
            { 
                result = result.Substring(1);
            }
            result = Path.Combine(wwwroot, result.Replace('/', '\\'));
        }

        return result;
    }

    public static string UnmapPath(this PlatformServices services, string path)
    {
        var result = path ?? string.Empty;
        if (services.IsPathMapped(path))
        {
            var wwwroot = services.WwwRoot();
            result = result.Remove(0, wwwroot.Length);
            result = result.Replace('\\', '/');

            var prefix = (result.StartsWith("/", StringComparison.Ordinal) ? "~" : "~/");
            result = prefix + result;
        }

        return result;
    }

    public static bool IsPathMapped(this PlatformServices services, string path)
    {
        var result = path ?? string.Empty;
        return result.StartsWith(services.Application.ApplicationBasePath,
            StringComparison.Ordinal);
    }

    public static string WwwRoot(this PlatformServices services)
    {
        // todo: take it from project.json!!!
        var result = Path.Combine(services.Application.ApplicationBasePath, "wwwroot");
        return result;
    }
}
```

**EDIT3:** `PlatformServices.WwwRoot()` return the actual execution path and in .net core 2.0, DEBUG mode it is xxx\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0, which, obviously is not what is required. Instead, replace `PlatformServices` with `IHostingEnvironment` and use `environment.WebRootPath`.

Comment: post a complete .net core 2.0 / 2.1 sample?