# Getting and storing the path of file in asp.net 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In previous version of asp.net the `HostingEnvironment` had `MapPath` method to get and store the path of the file but in ASP.net 5 I can't use it.

```
var filepath = HostingEnvironment.MapPath(@"~/Data/product.json");
```

Comment: You may get an instance of type `Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment` from DI, it has `MapPath` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using RC1?
In RC1 it depends if you are writing a console or web app. In console apps, you cannot use DI anymore but `PlatformServices.Default`.

`PlatformServices.Default.Application` gives you access to the base path of your application for example. The type of the static property is `IRuntimeEnvironment`. And having the base path of your app, you can easily build the path to files you need...

If you are building a web app, you should be able to inject `IRuntimeEnvironment` to your startup and use it from there.

You have to add a reference to the `Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions` package to all that stuff.

See also [my post here](http://michaconrad.com/Documentation/Blog/aspnet_5_accessing_environment_variables) for more details

Answer (score 0):

Despite `IHostingEnvironment` provides `MapPath()` method you may also need `UnmapPath()` too. Another useful method might be `IsPathMapped()`.

You can find all of them here: [Reading a file in MVC 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30656089/reading-a-file-in-mvc-6/35459834#35459834).

And all of them, thanks to `PlatformServices` availability, work in **Consolse**, **MVC**, and **ClassLib** apps.

HTH