# how to get server.MapPath in asp.net core from inside a helper

Tags: asp.net-core

having a helper method like this:

```
 public static IHtmlContent Source(this IHtmlHelper html, string s)
 {
     var path = ServerMapPath() + "Views\\" + s;
```

I need to get the equivalent of Server.MapPath in asp.net core

Comment: Although late, see my answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30656089/reading-a-file-in-mvc-6/35459834#35459834.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to inject `IHostingEnvironment`. Then:

`var path = env.ContentRootPath + "Views\\" + s;`

in an html helper you can do this:

```
((IHostingEnvironment)html.ViewContext.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(IHostingEnvironment))).ContentRootPath;
```

Comment: found it like this: `((IHostingEnvironment)html.ViewContext.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(IHostingEnvironment))).ContentRootPath`

Comment: Better to use `Path.Combine` and not concatenation of strings

Comment: One can use injection in a razor view:     @inject IHostingEnvironment HostingEnvironment

Comment: for now this is obsolete, use `IWebHostEnvironment` instead

Answer (score 3):

### recommended Solution

I **recommend** Don't use a static class. You can keep something similar to your class, and register it as a singleton.

```
public class SourceClass
{
    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _webHostEnvironment;

    public SourceClass (IWebHostEnvironment webHostEnvironment)
    {
         _webHostEnvironment= webHostEnvironment;
    }

    private IHtmlContent Source(this IHtmlHelper html, string s)
    {
        string contentRootPath = _webHostEnvironment.ContentRootPath;
        Path.Combine(contentRootPath,"Views",s)
    }
}
```

Then, in Startup.ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddSingleton<SourceClass>();
```

Finally, inject `SourceClass` where you need it, instead of just statically referencing the class.

---

### Another Solution

(*Note :@regnauld provided this solution, but it had some drawbacks, which I thought would be fully answered*)

But if you want to use a static method you can do(Note:  In **.Net Core 3** `IHostingEnvironment` is absolute and `IWebHostEnvironment` must be used instead ):

- for *ServerPath* ,use

  ```
  ((IWebHostEnvironment)html.ViewContext.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(IWebHostEnvironment))).ContentRootPath
  ```

OR

- for *WebRootPath (wwwroot)* ,use

  ```
  ((IWebHostEnvironment)html.ViewContext.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(IWebHostEnvironment))).WebRootPath
  ```

in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55934673/9076865) you can find more details.

---

I also **recommend** that you use this code:

```
var path = Path.Combine(WebRootPath,"Views",s)
```

instead of

```
var path = WebRootPath + "Views\\" + s
```

to run the code on all **operating systems**.