# ASP.net Core: How to get file data from Service?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Good day. I need to get path of a specific .txt file. From Service class i can call `AppContext.BaseDirectory` and it get me path to folder where placed .exe:

`C:\Users\XXX\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\MyProject\src\MyProject\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.0"`

But what i need to do if i need to get file from path:

```
`C:\Users\XXX\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\MyProject\src\Core\Common\MyFile.txt`
```

Use fixed path - it's bad solution, i think

Comment: Could you be a little bit more explicit about what is known and what you are trying to figure out?

Comment: will the file always be held in a specific place and will it always be with the application your using?

Comment: @SimonPrice yep, i want to get some stored info from this file and it should be always with app

Answer (score 0):

you need to use something like this

```
Server.MapPath("~/files/myFile.txt")
```

which will get you to your file as long as your folder structure (based on this example) is

Root | Files | myFile.txt

Edit

my bad, there is no Server.MapPath in ASP.Net Core, take a look at this and this should give you the concept you need in addition with my answer here

[how to get server.MapPath in asp.net core from inside a helper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38483962/how-to-get-server-mappath-in-asp-net-core-from-inside-a-helper)

Comment: What 'Server' you talk about? `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server` or `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server` not contains method MapPath