# MapPath outside of controller ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to convert an MVC 5 project to MVC 6 with ASP.NET Core. In the old project, I had a static HTML helper class which I used to render inline css.

I used to be able to use `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(path)` to get the root outside a controller, but this exists in `System.Web` and so is not available to me.

What equivalent can I use in ASP.NET Core to `MapPath` outside of a Controller class (ie, I do not have access to `IHostingEnvironment`)

Comment: I suggest passing the `IHostingEnvironment` to the helper method from a point where you do have access to it.

Answer (score -2):

You may find the answer which is a complete solution (`MapPath(), IsPathMapped(), UnmapPath()`) to this question: [Reading a file in MVC 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30656089/reading-a-file-in-mvc-6/35459834#35459834).